# canvas.toDataURL("image/png") returns blank data

Tags: html, canvas, todataurl

I am trying to convert canvas to dataURL by calling canvas.dataURL() method. It is working proper for some images with size 938x657 but when I try same function with large image size(for eg. 3750x2625, 7500x5250, etc) it returns "data:,"

Code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = app.getThemeLocalStorage("imgPath");
img.onload = function()
{
    alert("width:"+img.width+" height:"+img.height);
    $("#DummyCanvas").attr("width", img.width + "px");
    $("#DummyCanvas").attr("height", img.height + "px");
    var dummyCAN = document.getElementById("DummyCanvas");
    var ctx = dummyCAN.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var data = dummyCAN.toDataURL("image/png");
    alert(data); //Alerts data url for image size 938x657 but blanks for 3750x2625
}
```

Any suggestion/solution?

Comment: Yes, alert shows correct width and height. Image is stored in same app. As I mentioned in description, same code is working for smaller image for eg.938x657.

Comment: I fed a 7500x5250 image into your code and it works fine (including dataURL) on my win10 machine when browsing with Chrome44, Firefox40 & Edge & IE11. If you post your image, I'll try using your exact image, but I can say your code will correctly get the full dataURL for my image. Are you getting a security warning (open the dev tools in your browser and check for security warnings in the console tab)?